# Django from Windows7 to ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, scrapy

I have coded a small project using Python/Django and Scrapy on my personal laptop which has Windows 7 as its OS. and I have GIT committed it into GitHub.
The problem is, I want to clone that same code from GitHub into another laptop which has Ubuntu 12.04 as its OS and not windows 7.

I am new to python and also new to Ubuntu, can someone please guide me through the proper steps.

Comment: Sounds like you should start learning how to use the terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T on Ubuntu last time I used it). When you're warmed up, go to [GitHub.com](https://github.com) and check out their tutorials.

Comment: You might find http://try.github.com useful to learn git on the command line.

Comment: Is there a specific part of the process that you're confused about? Otherwise, some googling should be sufficient as well.

Comment: @Keyser ooh subtle.. (to me at least)

Comment: Actually I have never used Ubuntu before, I will be new to it, so bit confused about, like in windows we have cmd, but i have heard ubuntu has terminal, i know no commands to use it..

Comment: @user2631770 I took that into account in my answer. I assure you, it's a lot easier than it seems.

Comment: thank you...I will try my best..and in-case if i get stuck ..i hope people here will help me out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go about setting your own HTTP server & all that jazz, I highly suggest this tutorial. It's worked wonders for me on Ubuntu 12 LTS.

http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great tutorial on using the Terminal on Ubuntu:

[UsingTheTerminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal)

It's not directly related to your question, but if you're gonna start using Ubuntu you'll have to learn it at some point. (And you'll be installing most of your programs via the terminal).

Here's a link to GitHub's setup tutorial, which uses the Terminal:

[Set Up Git](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#platform-linux)

To clone a repo you use the command `git clone`. There's more info on how to do this available on the GitHub site.

An example of git clone:

> git clone https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools.git

The address to your repository can be found on its page on the GitHub site (on the lower right part of the page).

Installing Django is also very straight forward. There's some help on the site:

[Quick Install Guide (djangoproject.com)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/install/)

And if you run into trouble there are many tutorials available.

Also, I'm pretty sure Ubuntu ships with python.